# How to install an app written in Python?

Tags: installation, python

I tried to install an app written in Python using this command in terminal:

```
sudo make install
```

at the very last stage of installation, this message pops up:

```
[ -x /usr/bin/update-desktop-database ] && sudo update-desktop-database -q
```

I just want to know what it means and how to finish installation process.

Comment: You say "pops-up", you mean it is the last thing printed in the terminal?

Comment: Yes exactly. Although I have installed the program, there's no shortcut on my desktop.

Comment: Ubuntu installs don't make shortcuts on the desktop. What program are you trying to install?. Why did you install it from source?

Comment: @ Javier Rivera

Comment: @JavierRivera - I'm trying to install ldoce5viewer. Here's the website: [link](https://github.com/ciscorn/ldoce5viewer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
[ -x /usr/bin/update-desktop-database ] && sudo update-desktop-database -q
```

means "if `/usr/bin/update-desktop-database` exists and is executable then run `sudo update-desktop-database -q`.

The command `update-desktop-database` creates a database of MIME type handlers from the information found in the `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications`,  `/usr/local/share/applications` and `$HOME/.local/share/applications`.

Most likely the installation process is finished now and you should be able to use the app.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. But I still can't find the program's shortcut on my desktop. I entered the command "update-desktop-database" but nothing special happened. What should I do?

Comment: Have a look at [How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand/)